# AndroidStudio Error After configured SDK path

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I download the (android studio and android sdk) zip file.

[After configured SDK path, open the configuration has been loading the SDK Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAPNN.png)

```
2016-10-11 22:58:43,193 [1355018]   INFO - nfigure.SdkUpdaterConfigurable - Parsing J:\Android\sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-23\package.xml 
2016-10-11 22:58:43,193 [1355018]   INFO - nfigure.SdkUpdaterConfigurable - Parsing J:\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\package.xml 
2016-10-11 22:58:43,209 [1355034]   INFO - nfigure.SdkUpdaterConfigurable - Parsing J:\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\package.xml 
2016-10-11 22:58:43,209 [1355034]   INFO - nfigure.SdkUpdaterConfigurable - Parsing legacy package: J:\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.3 
2016-10-11 22:58:43,225 [1355050]  ERROR - pplication.impl.LaterInvocator - tried to access method com.android.sdklib.AndroidVersion$AndroidVersionException.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V from class com.android.sdklib.AndroidVersionHelper 
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.android.sdklib.AndroidVersion$AndroidVersionException.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V from class com.android.sdklib.AndroidVersionHelper
    at com.android.sdklib.AndroidVersionHelper.create(AndroidVersionHelper.java:71)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.local.LocalSdk.scanPlatforms(LocalSdk.java:908)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.local.LocalSdk.getPkgsInfos(LocalSdk.java:548)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.LegacyLocalRepoLoader.parseLegacyLocalPackage(LegacyLocalRepoLoader.java:100)
    at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.parsePackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:176)
    at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.getPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:154)
    at com.android.repository.impl.manager.RepoManagerImpl$LoadTask.run(RepoManagerImpl.java:653)
    at com.android.repository.api.RepoManager$DummyProgressRunner.runSyncWithProgress(RepoManager.java:398)
    at com.android.repository.impl.manager.RepoManagerImpl.load(RepoManagerImpl.java:387)
    at com.android.repository.api.RepoManager.loadSynchronously(RepoManager.java:290)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler$RepoConfig.createRepoManager(AndroidSdkHandler.java:695)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.getSdkManager(AndroidSdkHandler.java:269)
    at com.android.tools.idea.updater.configure.SdkUpdaterConfigurable.getRepoManager(SdkUpdaterConfigurable.java:128)
    at com.android.tools.idea.updater.configure.SdkUpdaterConfigPanel.validate(SdkUpdaterConfigPanel.java:462)
    at com.android.tools.idea.updater.configure.SdkUpdaterConfigPanel.refresh(SdkUpdaterConfigPanel.java:444)
    at com.android.tools.idea.updater.configure.SdkUpdaterConfigPanel.reset(SdkUpdaterConfigPanel.java:532)
    at com.android.tools.idea.updater.configure.SdkUpdaterConfigurable.reset(SdkUpdaterConfigurable.java:262)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.ConfigurableWrapper.reset(ConfigurableWrapper.java:187)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.ConfigurableCardPanel.reset(ConfigurableCardPanel.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.ConfigurableCardPanel$1.compute(ConfigurableCardPanel.java:80)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.ConfigurableCardPanel$1.compute(ConfigurableCardPanel.java:65)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:962)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.ConfigurableCardPanel.create(ConfigurableCardPanel.java:65)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.ConfigurableEditor$1.create(ConfigurableEditor.java:70)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.ConfigurableEditor$1.create(ConfigurableEditor.java:67)
    at com.intellij.ui.CardLayoutPanel.createValue(CardLayoutPanel.java:87)
    at com.intellij.ui.CardLayoutPanel.select(CardLayoutPanel.java:115)
    at com.intellij.ui.CardLayoutPanel.access$100(CardLayoutPanel.java:40)
    at com.intellij.ui.CardLayoutPanel$1$1.run(CardLayoutPanel.java:134)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:345)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:329)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:857)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:658)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:386)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:792)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:465)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.invokeShow(DialogWrapper.java:1661)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1610)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.SettingsDialog.access$001(SettingsDialog.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.SettingsDialog$1.run(SettingsDialog.java:80)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbPermissionServiceImpl.allowStartingDumbModeInside(DumbPermissionServiceImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbService.allowStartingDumbModeInside(DumbService.java:283)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.SettingsDialog.show(SettingsDialog.java:77)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowSettingsUtilImpl.showSettingsDialog(ShowSettingsUtilImpl.java:114)
    at com.android.tools.idea.updater.configure.RunSdkConfigAction.actionPerformed(RunSdkConfigAction.java:47)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.FlatWelcomeFrame$FlatWelcomeScreen$IconsFreeActionGroup$1.actionPerformed(FlatWelcomeFrame.java:652)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.PopupFactoryImpl$ActionPopupStep.performAction(PopupFactoryImpl.java:861)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.PopupFactoryImpl$ActionPopupStep$1.run(PopupFactoryImpl.java:847)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:857)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:658)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:386)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
2016-10-11 22:58:43,225 [1355050]  ERROR - pplication.impl.LaterInvocator - Android Studio 2.2.1  Build #AI-145.3330264 
2016-10-11 22:58:43,225 [1355050]  ERROR - pplication.impl.LaterInvocator - JDK: 1.8.0_76-release 
2016-10-11 22:58:43,225 [1355050]  ERROR - pplication.impl.LaterInvocator - VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
2016-10-11 22:58:43,225 [1355050]  ERROR - pplication.impl.LaterInvocator - Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o 
2016-10-11 22:58:43,225 [1355050]  ERROR - pplication.impl.LaterInvocator - OS: Windows 7 
2016-10-11 22:58:43,225 [1355050]  ERROR - pplication.impl.LaterInvocator - Last Action:
```

Comment: If it's fresh installation try to re-install Android Studio.

Comment: Finally, I re-install Android Studio Solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I re-install Android Studio Solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Try this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=222920&sort=-modified&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Modified).Hope it solve your problem too.